# Event.observe(window, "load", function(){..} v/s window.onload = function(){..}

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Even though both do the samething, i just want to know is there any specific advantage using one over another?

```
Event.observe(window, "load", function(){
//do something
});

window.onload = function(){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that `window.onload` is defined in the DOM Level 0 Event Model and will erase all earlier registed events. It's an 'native' call from an old API.

The `Event.observe` from the prototype javascript framework will determine the best event attacher available. A facade pattern. In modern browsers, the `addEventListener` will be called - `attachEvent` in case of Internet Explorer below version 9. In old browsers the `onload` will be called.

It obvious that a facade will choose the best option available, like `Event.observe` for prototype or `.load` in case of jQuery for example.

The methods from the DOM Level 2 Event Model are preferred over the DOM Level 0 Event Model methods because they act as observers and don't erase previous handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Read quirksmode.org's [introduction into events](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). The difference is between the [traditional model](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) and the [advanced models](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html), which need a wrapper because M$ does/did not support the W3-standard and a distinction needs to be made.